# SSRS or SQL Numbers Rounding/Truncating In SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services

I am using SSRS to write a report and I am running into a very strange issue.
I have numbers that are rounding that I do not want to round.

Below are the expressions that are in play.
I have formatted the textbox to display 4 decimals, default, money, custom, and others with no luck.
The numbers have the correct decimals to begin with.

So below are the expressions I am using.

**Why are the results rounding or truncating when the OR operator is used????**

New to SSRS and SQL in general.

Textbox1 has this Expression in it

```
IIf(Fields!SelQty.Value=1,Fields!EstPrice1.Value * Fields!Qty1.Value,0)
```

Results

```
2252.2800,
191.3205,
505.2300,
240.8000`
```

Textbox2 has this Expression in it

```
IIf(Fields!SelQty.Value=2,Fields!EstPrice2.Value * Fields!Qty2.Value,0)`
```

Results

```
81500.0400,
5914.0800,
58166.1600
```

Change Textbox1 to this Expression =

```
IIf(Fields!SelQty.Value=1,Fields!EstPrice1.Value * Fields!Qty1.Value,0)
```

**OR**

```
IIf(Fields!SelQty.Value=2,Fields!EstPrice2.Value * Fields!Qty2.Value,0)
```

Results

```
2252,
191,
505,
241,
81500,
5914,
58166
```

Comment: I don't understand the meaning of your final expression. What you do is something like this: =2252.2800 OR 81500.0400 so maybe SSRS don't treated your numbers as double.

Answer (score 1):

[`OR` here is a bitwise operator](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255271.aspx)

So `2252.2800 OR 0` gives `2252` because of some type casting. Personally, I've never bitwised numeric numbers so don't know how it works

Why use OR anyway: it makes no sense with `Iif`*at all*. What are you really try to do?

Nested `Iif` like this?

```
=IIf(
       Fields!SelQty.Value=1, 
       Fields!EstPrice1.Value * Fields!Qty1.Value,
       IIf(
             Fields!SelQty.Value=2, 
             Fields!EstPrice2.Value * Fields!Qty2.Value,
             0
           )
     )
```

Comment: Like i said I am new at this, so a nested IIF is what I need.